# Setting entity state when modifying complex properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible for Entity Framework Core to set an entity's state to `Modified` when a value in one of its properties is modified? I'd like to know this because I've overridden `Context.SaveChanges()` to auto-update columns based on the entity state.

For example, I have the following entity classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible, that by modifying `Bar.Name` by accessing it from an instance of `Foo`, that `Foo` will have its entity state be `Modified`? Like so:

```
var myFoo = context.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 11);
myFoo.Bar.Name = "Test";
context.SaveChanges();
```

When I inspect the changed entities via `ChangeTracker.Entries()`, I see `Bar` is modified but not `Foo`.

Comment: What is the change on Foo that you expect? If both Foo and Bar are mapped to tables, I think EF correctly recognizes that only Bar was updated...Am I missing something?

Comment: @Val Yes, in our schema `Foo` and `Bar` are mapped to their own tables. In this case EF recognizes `Bar` is modified, but I want to know if it possible to set `Foo` to be updated as well, since I'd like to reflect on the database that `Foo` was updated (e.g. set its last modified time), since the `Bar` related to it was updated.

Comment: From database point of view (i.e. the EF point of view), the changes in the two tables are not related and it is not reasonable to automatically update the last modified time on a table that was not actually changed. Perhaps someone else could think of a better solution, but I would just set the last modified date manually on myFoo when myFoo.Bar.Name is changed...